# Why is Document.html() so slow?

Tags: performance, jsoup

I was under the impression that the most costly method in Jsoup's API is [parse()](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file).

But I just discovered that [Document.html()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html%28%29) could be even slower.

Given that the `Document` is the output of `parse()` (i.e. this is *after* parsing), I find this surprising.

Why is `Document.html()` so slow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering myself. The [Element.html()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.java?av=f) method is implemented as:

```
public String html() {
  StringBuilder accum = new StringBuilder();
  html(accum); 
  return accum.toString().trim();
}
```

Using StringBuilder instead of String is already a good thing, and the use of `StringBuilder.toString()` and `String.trim()` may not explain the slowness of `Document.html()`, even for a relatively large document.

But in the middle, our method calls an overloaded version, `Element.html(StringBuilder)` which loops through all child nodes in the document:

```
private void html(StringBuilder accum) {
  for (Node node : childNodes)
    node.outerHtml(accum);
}
```

Thus if the document contains lots of child nodes, it *will* be slow.

It would be interesting to see whether there could be a faster implementation of this.

For example, if Jsoup stores a **cached** version of the **raw** html that was provided to it via `Jsoup.parse()`. As an option of course, to maintain backward compatibility and small footprint in memory.